# display user ratings in laravel

Tags: laravel, e-commerce

**want to fetch ratings from database. it works fine but I thought it not an efficient way. can someone suggest me better!**

```
database value for user star ratings 5,4,3,...1
```

here I check if user ratings =5 then it shows 5 star on frontend. using if else but use 5 times is not good .how i use for loop here?

```
@foreach($ratings as $rating)
                        <div class="about-author">
                            <div class="author-text">
                                <img src="{{asset('/')}}/theme/img/blog/1.png" alt="" />
                                <div class="author-des">
                                    <h4><a href="#">{{$rating->name}}</a></h4>
                                    <span class="floatright ratting">
                                        @if($rating->star ==5)
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                        @endif
                                            @if($rating->star ==1)
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                            @endif
                                            @if($rating->star ==2)
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                            @endif
                                            @if($rating->star ==3)
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                            @endif
                                            @if($rating->star ==4)
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                                            @endif
                                            </span>
                                    <span>{{ $rating->updated_at->format('jS F \\, Y h:i:s A') }}</span>
                                    <p>{{$rating->review}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <hr />
                        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `@for` loop to determine how many to show:

```
@for($i = 1; $i <= $rating->star; $i++)
  <i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
@endfor
```

This of course assumes the existence of the rating, so it's probably best to check if they've rated it as well.